# Change of speed problem (differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem**

Let $V: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lipschitz continuous vector field, and let $k: \mathbb{R}^n \to (0,\infty)$ be a positive Lipschitz continuous function. Let ${x_t}$ be a solution to $\dot{x} = V(x)$ with initial condition $\xi$, and let ${y_t}$ be a solution to $\dot{x}=k(x)V(x)$, also with initial condition $\xi$. Show that $y_t=x_{I(t)}$, where $$I(t)=\int_{0}^{t} k(y_s)ds$$
[Note: $x_{I(t)}$ means $x(I(t))$.]

---

**Attempt**:

By the uniqueness theorem, we just have to show that $x_{I(t)}$ satisfies $\dot{x}=k(x)V(x)$  (that it then satisfies the initial condition is obvious).

Let $z(t)\equiv x(I(t))$.

$\dot{z}(t)= \dot{x}(I(t))k(y(t))=V(x_{I(t)}))k(y(t))$ where the first equality follows by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the second by definition of $x$. We need to show this equals $V(z(t)) \cdot k(z(t)) = V(x_{I(t)}) \cdot k(x_{I(t)}) $. I know I'm going to have to use the definition of $\dot{y}$ somewhere but not seeing where. I guess I can try to show $k(x_{I(t)})=k(z(t))$ but don't know if that's any easier than the original.

The intuitive idea is that $k$ speeds up the trajectory so $y(t)$ will be like $x(I(t))$ where $I(t)$ scales up $t$ based on an average of the speeding up factor $k$ along the path.

Hints welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of notation is almost guaranteed to cause confusion.

Let $x$ be the solution of $\dot{a}(t) = V(a(t))$ subject to $x(0) = \xi$.

Let $y$ be the solution of $\dot{a}(t) = k(a(t))V(a(t))$ subject to $a(0) = \xi$.

Let $w$ be the solution of $\dot{a}(t) = k(y(t))V(a(t))$ subject to $a(0) = \xi$, where $y$ is the $y$ from the previous paragraph.

Let $I(t) =\int_0^t k(y(s))ds$.

Note that $w=y$.

Let $z(t) = x(I(t))$, we want to show that $z=y$.

Note that $\dot{z}(t) = \dot{x}(I(t))\dot{I}(t) =  V(x(I(t)))k(y(t)) = k(y(t))V(z(t)) $ and $z(0) = \xi$.

Hence $z=w=y$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but I didn't understand your answer and figured someone's downvote indicated it was wrong. I get $\dot{z}(t)= \frac{d}{dt}x(I(t))=x(I(t))k(y(t))=V(x_{I(t)}))k(y(t))=V(x_{z(t)}))k(y(t))$ but your answer has $z$ instead of $y$ in $k(\cdot)$. I don't understand that. Can you please clarify? You also have a couple missing parens btw.

Comment: @Smithey: My answer was a little glib and not at all clear. I have elaborated a bit. The key is the transition from the $y$ ode. to the $w$ ode.